# Calculate business days in future to send reminder emails

Tags: c#, function, datetime

I am working on this employee performance review application. I need to send out reminder emails when the user has left 3 and 1 business days before the end of the 15 business day period.

**Here is how I plan on doing it:**
 I have the Last Modified Date for each Review which I should be able to use to find out 15 business days in future(call it deadLineToSubmit for our example). Once I got deadLineToSubmit I should check to see if currentDate + 3 days(date) == deadLineToSubmit Then add that review to my list which I will be using to send email.

I have a function called GetByDayPrior where I am sending values 3 and 1 to check if user have left 3 business days or 1. Below is the code:

```
    public List<int> GetByDaysPrior(int daysPrior)
    {
        List<int> response = new List<int>();

        using (DAL.HumanResourcesEntities context = new DAL.HumanResourcesEntities())
        {
            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
            var lastModifiedDate = context.Reviews
                                    .Where(s => s.IsActive == false)
                                    .Where(s => s.ReviewStatusId == (int)ReviewStatuses.EmployeeSignature)
                                    .Select(v => v.ModifiedDate)
                                    .ToList();
            AddBusinessDays(lastModifiedDate, daysPrior);

            var lastRuntime = context.ApplicationRuntimeVariables.Where(y => y.ParameterName == "RemindersSentDT").Select(x => x.ParameterValue).FirstOrDefault().Date;

            DateTime deadLineToSubmitReview = currentDate.AddDays(daysPrior).Date;
            if (lastRuntime.AddHours(24).Date <= currentDate) //should it be == current date ?
            {
                var reviewIDs = context.Reviews
                                        .Where(s => s.ModifiedDate < deadLineToSubmitReview)
                                        .Where(s => s.ReviewStatusId == (int)ReviewStatuses.EmployeeSignature) //Check to make sure reminders only go when Review Status is Employee Signature
                                        .Where(s => s.IsActive == false)
                                        .Select(v => v.ReviewId)
                                        .ToList();

                response = reviewIDs.ToList();
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
```

I have another function called AddBusinessDays should give me the deadLineToSubmit when I pass in LastModifiedDate and 15 days as parameter. But currently its not working because firstly I cannot find out how to pass List of DataTime as a paramater in this function. Also when I defined date parameter in AddBusinessDays as List now all the instances of date and DayOfWeek are complanining

> "Error   32  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.DateTime'

Below is my AddBusinessDays function.

```
 public static DateTime AddBusinessDays(List<DateTime> date, int days)
    {
        if (days < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("days cannot be negative", "days");
        }

        if (days == 0) return date;

        if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            date = date.AddDays(2);
            days -= 1;
        }
        else if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            date = date.AddDays(1);
            days -= 1;
        }

        date = date.AddDays(days / 5 * 7);
        int extraDays = days % 5;

        if ((int)date.DayOfWeek + extraDays > 5)
        {
            extraDays += 2;
        }

        return date.AddDays(extraDays);

    }
```

**Here's what I need to know:** How to send DateTime List as parameter in AddBusinessDays function. How to make AddBusinessDays function work because now we are passing list instead of single dateTime. Is my thinking logic correct to solve this issue ?

Thanks a Lot! :)

Comment: Error message is clear. Your `date` is `List<DateTime>` but you wanna use `AddDays` method with it like a `DateTime`. Have you _ever_ consider to  iterate your values within?

Comment: @SonerGönül I am open to it. How can I achieve that ? Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: It's not clear to me *why* you are passing `date` as a `List<DateTime>` in the first place? Is there supposed to be more than one date it's working on? Or is it only ever supposed to be a list with one date? If the later, then instead of `ToList` at the end of your LINQ statement, use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` to get just a single `DateTime` instead of a collection with one member.

Comment: I want to pass multiple Review LastModifiedDate's into AddBusinessDays. @MattBurland

Comment: @HereToLearn_: Well, then for starters you should chose better variable names. Collections should have plural names. So `lastModifiedDates` and your `AddBusinessDays` should take an argument called `dates`. Then all you need to do is iterate your collection and apply whatever operations you need to *each* `DateTime` object.

Answer (score 1):

date is a list and not a single date.
You can make an operation on all items of the list by using `Select`
for example:

```
lastModifiedDate = AddBusinessDays(lastModifiedDate, daysPrior);
```

Step 1: Convert your function to receive a single date

```
private static DateTime AddBusinessDays(DateTime date, int days)
{
    if (days < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("days cannot be negative", "days");
    }

    if (days == 0) return date;

    if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        date = date.AddDays(2);
        days -= 1;
    }
    else if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        date = date.AddDays(1);
        days -= 1;
    }

    date = date.AddDays(days / 5 * 7);
    int extraDays = days % 5;

    if ((int)date.DayOfWeek + extraDays > 5)
    {
        extraDays += 2;
    }

    return date.AddDays(extraDays);
}
```

Step 2: Use the single date function for the list of dates

```
public static List<DateTime> AddBusinessDays(List<DateTime> date, int days)
{
    return date.Select(d => AddBusinessDays(d, days)).ToList();
}
```